# What's the [rollover] tag (request to rename)

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I can't even translate that rollover properly (No, it's not the rollover when you drive your mouse over a widget and it detects that event)

There's only **one** question contain that tag and I don't really get it...

Can we close this tag?

I have looked at the wrong tabulator - you are very right there are **more** questions!!! but the [Daily rollover for a FileOutputStream using Protocol Buffers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059606/daily-rollover-for-a-fileoutputstream-using-protocol-buffers) featured question uses it in a wrong context...

So I must pick up the idea from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1234256/mooseman and rename it into **[mouseover]** to stop mixing it up!!

I was really confused when I tried to get the point (translate it)...

Comment: I see [372 questions tagged rollover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rollover)

Comment: ps you may want to tag with [burninate-request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) too

Comment: Seems like most should be retagged [tag:mouseover].

Comment: @Tanner thanks for pointing that out - i must confess i did a wrong query when posting this question. but still Mooseman is right, we should rename it! i was totally confused by the use of this english word...

Comment: I cleaned up a few questions that had to do with rolling over log files or time rolling over.  I think everything that is left can be merged into [mouseover].